# Angular 2 updating var in arrow function - Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, typescript, angular, facebook-login

(Sorry about my English)

Hi, I'm still developing my website with Facebook login using Angular 2 and TypeScript. The people had helped me before with the arrows functions, but now I can't display the user information on the screen.
The login is successfully done, the this.user receives user data, but that information appears on the screen must I perform some action, for example, pressing a button (even without some event).

Code (app.component.ts):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Main} from './pages/main/main';

declare const FB: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.html',
  directives: [Main]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

token: any;
loged: boolean = false;
window.user = { name: 'Hello' };

constructor() { }

statusChangeCallback(response: any) {
    if (response.status === 'connected')
        this.me();
    else
        this.login();
}

login() {
    FB.login((result: any) => {
        this.loged = true;
        this.token = result;
        this.me();
    }, { scope: 'user_friends' });
}

me() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,gender,picture.width(150).height(150),age_range,friends',
        (result: any) => {
            console.log(result);
            this.user = result;
        });
}

ngOnInit() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(response => {
        this.statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}
}
```

I think that my problem is at the `me()` method.

Code (app/app.html):

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    User name: {{user.name}}
  </a>
</div>
```

I'm a beginner with Angulare 2 and typescript, so I'm still having problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the FB object is created outside the context of Angular2 so processing in callback won't trigger change detection.

You need to execute your code an Angular2 zone leveraging the `NgZone` class:

```
constructor(private ngZone:NgZone) {
}

me() {
  FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,gender,picture.width(150).height(150),age_range,friends',
    (result: any) => {
      console.log(result);
      this.ngZone.run(() => { // <-----
        this.user = result;
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're specifying `window.user` at the top of your component, but you're assigning a `user` variable. It's not really clear which one you're using in your template, but this looks like it's the source of your problem.